# Targeting parent object height

Tags: jquery

Working with Adobe's Edge Animate and jQuery.

I'm adding content using json files and adjusting the height of the "Stage" (Edge Animate's animation content area) using `$('#Stage').css({'height':newHeight});`

This works as expected.

When you embed the animation in a web page, it is placed in a "object" container.

`<object id="EdgeID" name="EdgeID" type="text/html" width = "940" height ="1020" data ="../public_html/edgeanimate_assets/import/Assets/import.html"></object>`

What I want to do is override the height of the `object#EdgeID` so that it matches the value set for the stage.

`$('#EdgeID').css({'height':newHeight})` from inside the animation script does not work.

What is the correct method for targeting the container `(object #EdgeID)`?

Comment: @undefined you missed a `>` before `</object>`.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead of `.css()`. The `height` is an *attribute* of the `<object>` element, rather than a CSS style property.

```
$('#EdgeID').attr('height', newHeight);
```

Comment: No difference when I use this.  I can set up a jQuery event outside the animation and affect the height of the object.  I just can't get an action inside the animation to affect the object in which it is embedded.

Answer (score 2):

Since an object element uses its `height` attribute for its height, as opposed to CSS rules, you will need to directly change that instead. Try:

```
$('#EdgeID').attr('height', newHeight);
```

`.attr()` docs: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: "as opposed to CSS rules" should probably be, "as opposed to an entry in the style attribute".

Comment: No difference when I use this. I can set up a jQuery event outside the animation and affect the height of the object. I just can't get an action inside the animation to affect the object in which it is embedded.